# React useEffect in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to find a way to use useEffect like this, but I don't think I'm doing it properly:

```
const [searching, setSearching] = useState(false);
function OnSearch(e) {
        const searchValue = e.target.value;
        useEffect(() => {
            setSearching(true);
        }, []);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            setSearching(false);
            window.location.href = '/block/' + searchValue;
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Any kind of help or direction will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need `useEffect` at this specific position. Just delete it and keep `setSearching(true);` and it works as you expect.

Comment: I tried that @MaiKaY but it actually seems break the `searchValue` redirect. If I type more than one character for `searchValue`, it strips it to 1 character.

Comment: See screencast here @MaiKaY https://share.getcloudapp.com/yAuY2NkP

Comment: To help you solve that problem, we'll need to have a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, preferably a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (Although I may have inadvertently fixed it by showing how to use non-state instance data in my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume from the `useState` you've used there that this code is inside a functional component. You don't need or want `useEffect` there, just remove it and do `setSearching(true)` directly:

```
const [searching, setSearching] = useState(false);
function OnSearch(e) {
    const searchValue = e.target.value;
    setSearching(true);
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setSearching(false);
        window.location.href = '/block/' + searchValue;
    }, 2000);
}
```

(In fact, not only do you not need it, but you can't use hooks anywhere other than the top level of a component function or hook function. So not in an event handler.)

That leaves the question of the `timer` variable. It can't just be a local variable in the component function because that will get recreated on every render. For non-state instance data like that, you can use an object via `useRef`, then use properties on that object, which will be consistent for the lifetime of the component:

```
const [instance] = useRef({});
```

So that gives us:

```
const [instance] = useRef({});
const [searching, setSearching] = useState(false);
function OnSearch(e) {
    const searchValue = e.target.value;
    setSearching(true);
    clearTimeout(instance.timer);
    instance.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setSearching(false);
        window.location.href = '/block/' + searchValue;
    }, 2000);
}
```

---

Side note: In JavaScript, the overwhelmingly-common convention is that only constructor functions and (in React) component functions are capitalized, not other kinds of functions. So `onSearch` rather than `OnSearch`. You can do what you like in your own code of course, but when working with others or asking for help, sticking to conventions helps keep communication clear.

Comment: Thanks for explaining but my issue was fixed by adding in methods for `onKeyUp` and `onKeyPress`.

Comment: @designtocode - I'm glad you fixed the issue. I assume you also stopped using `useEffect` in `OnSearch`...? Because if it's an event callback, you don't use `useEffect` there.

Comment: Yep I renamed it to `handleKeyUp` and just used `setSearching(true)` and it works as expected.