# How to use a function in React useEffect

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I want below code to be in `React useEffect` because every time things get changed I want the component to get rerender. But react does not allow `useEffect` in a function.

The below code is being toggled on click. Everything is working fine but the component does not reload so you need to switch between other components so that it gets updated.

```
const toggleFavorite = () => {
  if (docdata !== "") {
    db.collection("infodata")
      .doc(docdata)
      .set({
        favorite: !favoritePassword
      }, {
        merge: true
      });

    setFavoritePassword(!favoritePassword);
  }
};
```

```
<div onClick={toggleFavorite}>
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} />
</div>
```

---

I have tried these:
[React useEffect in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406727/react-useeffect-in-function)
[React Async Function wrapped in a UseEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434871/react-async-function-wrapped-in-a-useeffect)

But these do not seem to work.

Any help will be appreciated,

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you could do something like this:

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

const toggleFavorite = () => {
    if (docdata !== "") {
        db.collection("infodata")
            .doc(docdata)
            .set({
                favorite: !favoritePassword
            }, {
                merge: true
            });

        setFavoritePassword(!favoritePassword);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    toggleFavorite()
}, [toggle])

<div onClick={setToggle(!toggle)}>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} />
</div>
```